# How can make my InputLabel of a Select to open it (inside a FormControl)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Select with an InputLabel, but when I click on the InputLabel, the Select is not opening.
They are wrapped inside a FormControl because I need to do some control when there is an error.

Weird thing, when I remove the FormControl, I can click on the InputLabel to open the select.

In the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#simple-select) they are also using a FormControl with an InputLabel and a Select... Am I missing something ?

My component looks like this :

```js
<FormControl error={hasError}>
    <InputLabel id={someId}>{someText}</InputLabel>
    <Select labelId={someId} placeholder={someText} value={content.someValue || ''} onChange={changeValue}>
        {someObject.map((obj) => <MenuItem key={obj.id} value={obj.value}>{obj.name}</MenuItem>)}
    </Select>
    { hasError && <FormHelperText>{someError}</FormHelperText> }
</FormControl>
```

And the render look like this :
[image: select i'm talking about]

If I click on "Groupe d'organisateurs", nothing happens. If I click just above the text, the Select opens itself, and same if I click on the border or on the blank space next to the text.

Comment: Please create a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Well, i found the problem, there was a rule that put a "background-color" on the "MuiInputBase-root" selector thus hiding the label...
To see the label, I added a z-index on my label. Removing the background-color and the z-index did the work